# Open a contact by id from my application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this method:

```
    public void vercontacto(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(contactPickerIntent);
}
```

This method opens the androids contacts application from my application, i want to open a contact in the androids contacts application by id, i have declared the id in the class.How can I do it?
thanks